# Which element do I call to give padding or margin so I have space at the bottom

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have simple CSS3 navigation as below,
[image]

I need space just after the last list item of drop down menu called "Links to Our Clients". I would like to know which element need to be called.

HTML code

```
<ul class="menu">

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Why Us</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Meet the Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What our Client Say</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Promises</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Complete Profit Guide</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">How to choose an Accountant </a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Links to Our Clients</a></li>
    </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

<li><a href="#">RTI</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Company Foundation</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Auto Enrolment</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Client Area</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>


</ul>
```

css

```
/*
Author: Sana Khan
This Responsive web template using HTML5 CSS3 & Jquery
Links:
http://sanainfotech.co.uk/

*/

/* Reset */
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 }

 /* Menu */
 .menu {    
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;

 background: #292F45;
/*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);*/

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
  }

 .menu li {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 }

 /* Links */

 .menu li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 20px;
 margin: 6px 0;
 line-height: 28px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-left: 1px solid rgb(27, 31, 45);

 /*border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;*/

 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;

 color: #f3f3f3;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

 -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
 }

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a {
 color: #547AA6;
 }

/* Sub Menu */

.menu ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 left: 0;

 opacity: 0;

 background: #5379A5;


-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}



.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;

-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
 transition: height .25s ease .1s;
 }

.menu li:hover > ul li {
height: 23px;
overflow: visible;
padding: 0;

}

.menu ul li a {
width: 220px;
padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
margin: 0;  
border: none;

 }


 .menu ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
  color:#FFFFFF;
 }

 .menu ul li a ul{
    padding-bottom:4px;
 }
  .menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

 /* Icons */

.menu a.documents { background: url(../img/docs.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.messages { background: url(../img/bubble.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.signout { background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
```

Thanks in advance. I think some parent element property is effecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it either by putting a padding-bottom on either:

```
.menu ul
```

or

```
.menu ul li:last-child
```

Answer (score 1):

where you have the following:

```
.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
```

you set the padding to zero. Increasing the padding will add space to the bottom (but also in between each item). You could add the following:

```
.menu ul li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 10px;     //or however much space you want
}
```

This will only add padding to the bottom element (which seems like what you want)

As others have said, adding padding to `.menu ul` will have the same visual effect:

```
.menu ul {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place a padding at the **.menu li ul li.** It would style each **li** of your code. But you might not want this so add **padding-bottom** to your **.menu li ul**

You dont need last child or any other pseudo element
this should work:

```
 .menu li ul{
    padding-bottom:10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed you the [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/ntvqyb8w/)

```css
.menu ul li:last-child a {
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #547AA6;
}
```